# SharePoint online - retrieve deleted attachment of a list item

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is there a way to recover the deleted file that was an attachment in a SharePoint list item?

I checked in the Recycle bin and admin recycle bin as well and the file doesn't seem to be there

```
/_layouts/15/AdminRecycleBin.aspx?view=5
```

Answer (score 1):

Whether the list in the subsite or top-level site?

Who deleted the attachment? How long has the attachment been deleted?

If in the subsite, you could recover deleted attachment of a list item in the site recycle bin.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytest/subtest/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx
```

If in the top-level site, you could recover deleted attachment of a list item in the site collection recycle bin.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytest/_layouts/15/RecycleBin.aspx
```

Go to site contents -> Recycle bin.

[image]